# Module Not Found but package appears in sys.path

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

This is my first time trying to write code in a nice organized structure and am having trouble with importing.  Apologies if this is a dumb question. The module I want to import is in test package under smureader package

```
C:\User\Documents\Python Scripts\smureader\test\unittestExample.py
```

When I run `sys.path`:

```
['C:\\User\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\smureader',
 'C:\\User\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\smureader',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3',
 '',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Progra~1\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\J26612\\.ipython']
```

But when I try to import a class from `unittestExample.py`, I get an error

```
from smureader.test.unittestExample import TestStringMethods

Traceback (most recent call last):File "<ipython-input-4-5cc4a996aaee>", line 1, in <module>
from smureader.test.unittestExample import TestStringMethods ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smureader'
```

I'm really at a loss here. I have been trying to read up on `sys.path`, `PYTHONPATH` and imports but just getting more confused.  This is just one example, I can't import my modules from anywhere in my structure.

Comment: The parent of `smureader` needs to be in the path and all .py files and subdirectories containing `__init__.py` files are now modules.

Comment: It helps to pull the images into text and post them directly with the question. The directory tree may need a little ascii art.

Comment: Please don't use images for error messages, code and a simple directory structure: copy-paste into a code block, and use a bit of ASCII art for the directory structure. Definitely do not provide links to external images. Images can't be searched, and not every browser (screenreader) can display them.

Answer (score 0):

Directories in `sys.path` are scanned for .py files and subdirectories that also have `__init__.py` files. Those become importable modules and packages. You need the parent of the smureader directory in the path. With the warning that if you have other .py files there that shadow stdlib or installed modules, you may end up importing the wrong thing.

Comment: When I uses sys.path.append() to temporarily add the parent of smureader everything works great!  Thanks for the tip.  However, now I can't add the parent to my PYTHONPATH (grr).  I'm using the same steps to add the child but it just doesn't work

Comment: You'd need to add it to PYTHONPATH before calling the script. There is a mechanism to add it to your login, but I don't remember it off hand. In the end, making your stuff installable and doing an install is the gold standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `smureader` should be in the same directory as the file that imports it, otherwise you have to include the full path.

There is another way, and it is to put your file in this directory:

```
Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages
```